# Random or fixed effects in a GLM, or perhaps GEE?

Tags: logistic, generalized-estimating-equations, pre-post-comparison

I am involved in the analysis of the effect of an intervention at five different hospitals. The intervention aimed to increase the use of a particular equipment when treating a patient, so the outcome variable is binary (used the equipment/did not use the equipment). The study is not controlled, just pre- and post intervention measurements, with different patients before and after the intervention, so just two independent groups.

However, the hospitals are very different with different types of patients. To account for this clustering, I initially considered a logistic regression model with *"equipment use"* as an dependent variable and *time* (pre vs post) and *hospital* as independent fixed effect models, possibly with an interaction term.

However, recently I have received a suggestion that a GEE would be a preferred choice instead of a logistic regression. I guess this person sees *hospital* as a random factor, and therefore would like me to consider an population-averaged effect (the population in this case being the hospitals). Does anyone have any thoughts on this? I don't see the advantage of this approach, but I get a feeling that I am missing something crucial. Are there any other suggestions for analysis?

The aim of the study is to examine the effect of the intervention, the hospitals per se are not of interest. They are just five convenience sampled hospitals, certainly not a random sample.